# Backbone.js - Back button restoring scroll position

Tags: backbone.js

I've got a web application written in backbone.js.  Say I have a page of search results and the user is scrolled to the bottom of the search results.  The user clicks on the last search result, and the page is displayed for that result.

I want to support back button, and when the user clicks "back", the router kicks in and redisplays the search page.  Problem is when the search page is re-rendered , its scrolled to the top again.

What is the best way to restore the results to the original position?

Answer (score 1):

Consider tracking the scroll position in the view. Then on a `render` or let the `route` change position the page

```
View = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function () {
      var self = this;
      $( window ).on( 'scroll', function () {
         self.position = this.pageYOffset;
      });

   },
   render: function () {
      // render code
      if ( this.position ) {
        window.scrollBy( 0, this.position );
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Instead of binding the window scroll event (which caused problems when managing the scroll position for multiple views), I chose to grab the pageYOffset + save it upon changing view instead.